# Simulate a click on span tag in enzyme

Tags: reactjs, sinon, enzyme, sinon-chai

I have a span tag in my component and I need to click it using enzyme

```
    <span className="lock"> 
    <span onClick={[undefined]} id="lock">
    <i className="fa fa-lock" />
    Reserve this chat
    </span>
    </span>
```

Here is my test

```
it('simulating reservechat click ...',()=>{
const wrapper=shallow(<ReserveChat activeConversation={conversation1} />);
const button=wrapper.find('span').last();
button.simulate('click');
});
```

I am confused to find what to click,usually there will be some div class or other findable tags

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a ref attribute on your span element, like :

```
<span onClick={this.props.lockConversation} ref='chat-button'>
```

And then, I'm not that familiar with enzyme, but seems to me that something like

```
const button=wrapper.ref('chat-button');
```

should work, if I read their doc properly.

Comment: It should not be necessary to add a ref for the purpose of writing tests if it is not needed for the component's normal function. There should be another way.